# Language for a warning sign in a place like a library

Tags: imperative-sentences

Which sign would be more appropriate in a place like library:

> Please don't make noise.
>
> Do not make noise.
>
> Keep quiet.

I mean when should we prefer to use " Do not do that" and when should we prefer to use " please do/don't do it"

Comment: Libraries are no longer places of silence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic wording for a library sign is "[quiet please](http://www.nyls.edu/library/library-information/quiet_please/)".

I don't think there is a hard and fast *rule* for what to say, but in general, it seems like the more important and critical the rule, the more forceful the choice of words is.  A sign that advises you to be polite or that is trying to be helpful usually says "please".  For example:

[image]

or

[image]

But signs warning of danger, laws, or rules that will be strictly enforced usually do not say "please":

[image]

or

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With signage, space is often at a premium, and most people do not have the patience to read a multi-word sign. Brevity is therefore often the key.

> danger
>
> no smoking
>
> no admission
>
> fire exit

For the library,

> silence

... maybe followed by a grudging 'please'.

Comment: excuse me what do you mean by arpt..

Comment: @Mrt Looks like a typo. Pretty certain this edit is what was meant.